# How to log user in with Parse Server?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a simple website in node where I have user log in. Since switching from parse.com to Parse Server some things are different and I cant figure out how to solve it.

Im trying to login a user, then redirect them to the /home page like so:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password, {
  success: function(user) {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
    console.log('user: ' + user);
    res.redirect('/home');
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
    console.log('error login');
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});

});
```

Then once landed in /home, i run this:

```
app.get('/home',function(req, res){

if (Parse.User.current()) {
      // No need to fetch the current user for querying Note objects.
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  var sessionToken = currentUser.get('sessionToken');

  console.log(sessionToken);
    }
});
```

Doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: get no logs from console.log?

Comment: What does not seem to work? In "/home" you check if the user has already logged in and is that true? What are you trying to do? Your code looks OK to me.

Comment: i read somewhere that Parse.User.current is no valid anymore, i believe /login post works the login is succesful, but when i get to /home it doesnt detect currentuser

Comment: @Loolooii basically whats happening is when i console.log Parse.User.current it returns null

Comment: Why are you logging the user in server-side? That should be done client-side.

Comment: Im doing it for a website.

Comment: @Loolooii i just followed this https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#hosting-express-middleware

Comment: It says that the middleware only works if your app is accessed through an https connection! Are you sure you are following the steps exactly and your app supports https?

Comment: Yes im sure it supports it.